# How do I give different colors to specific text in Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want to give color to some of my website text. My website in on WordPress.I try with my Elementor free version but It looks not professional. I want a 3rd party addons for solve the probelm.

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on the Elementor Text Block and navigate to the "Style" tab. Then change de "Color" option.